# How to Update line Total on checkout page in woocommerece

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need the Hook or any plugin by which I can update the product Line Total on check-out page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the template `woocommerce\templates\cart\cart-totals.php` but editing it directly is not a good practice. So copy the entire `templates` directory and paste it in your active theme. Then rename the directory `templates` to `woocommerce`.

In the file `cart-totals.php` search for HTML class `order-total` this `tr` holds the text to display under `th` header.

Or else if you like to get total price.

`WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;`